# The trait bound `LockedFlahs: ReadNorFlash` is not satisfied

Tags: rust, embedded

I am trying to read from a flash sector on my stm32f429. I am using the stm32f4xx_hal crate using the flash peripheral. I am using the exact example from the [rust docs](https://docs.rs/stm32f4xx-hal/latest/stm32f4xx_hal/flash/struct.LockedFlash.htmt),

```
use stm32f4xx_hal::pac::Peripherals;
use stm32f4xx_hal::flash::LockedFlash;
use embedded_storage::nor_flash::ReadNorFlash;

let dp = Peripherals::take().unwrap();
let mut flash = LockedFlash::new(dp.FLASH);
println!("Flash capacity: {}", ReadNorFlash::capacity(&flash));

let mut buf = [0u8; 64];
ReadNorFlash::read(&mut flash, 0x0, &mut buf).unwrap();
println!("First 64 bytes of flash memory: {:?}", buf);
```

`Cargo check` produces the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `LockedFlash: ReadNorFlash` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:114:32
    |
114 |             ReadNorFlash::read(&mut flash,0x0, &mut buf).unwrap();
    |             ------------------ ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ReadNorFlash` is not implemented for `LockedFlash`
    |             |
    |             required by a bound introduced by this call

error[E0277]: the trait bound `LockedFlash: ErrorType` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:114:13
    |
114 |             ReadNorFlash::read(&mut flash,0x0, &mut buf).unwrap();
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ErrorType` is not implemented for `LockedFlash`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `LockedFlash: ErrorType` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:114:13
    |
114 |             ReadNorFlash::read(&mut flash,0x0, &mut buf).unwrap();
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ErrorType` is not implemented for `LockedFlash`
```

I have included the embedded-storage crate in my Cargo.toml, which is where the ReadNorFlash trait comes from. In the documentation is says that `ReadNorFlash` is a type implementation for `LockedFlash`...

I have had something similar happen before and it was an issue with lifetimes, that does not seem to be the case here as there is no specified lifetime in the docs. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please show us the _complete_ error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE).

Comment: Most probable cause for this error: you have multiple versions of `embedded-storage` in your project, and your code and `stm32f4xx_hal` use different versions. You can run `cargo tree` to check the versions used.